# Split the file content equally in ruby

Tags: ruby, split

I'm reading a file (input.txt) and trying to split the contents with '*' as the delimiter and below is the code I came up with but it assigns all the values to the first list i.e. uno instead of splitting equally. Where I'm doing it wrong. Many thanks for any help.

One more scenario - how to split the contents equally even though we have no idea how many lines are separated with * .In other words, here 3 rows are separated with the delimiter of multiple *s. What if in case of 1000 + rows and 1000 + delimiter of multiple *s.

input.txt

```
Record: C:/my_files/00_Roll_Tom-values.txt

#RakeBoss-Random as on 12/19/2016
[groups]
met = chk\rel_io_chk, chk\dev_op_io, chk\yuijn7, chk\rft65y
div = chk\ret5cf, chk\plo09i, chk\czo987, chk\lopikm, chk\qzt0kc
rakeonly = chk\r7ynsd, chk\bhtw5h, chk\ko9ibv, chk\plot9q
*******************************************************************************************
Record: C:/my_files/Docker_red-values.txt

#RakeBoss-Check it io.
[groups]
met = chk\rel_io_chk, chk\dev_op_io, chk\yuijn7
div = chk\gzlqvg, chk\k7ygyp, chk\lzg0rp, chk\oli6iv
rakeonly = chk\qzliu0, chk\pl6w6t, chk\bzp0l, chk\dzfbhp
*******************************************************************************************
Record: C:/my_files/456_Milo_123-values.txt

#RakeBoss-Jan 21st Prod
[groups]
met = chk\rel_io_chk, chk\dev_op_io
div = chk\ret5cf, chk\plo09i, chk\cz0o9t, chk\lopikm
rakeonly = chk\ztylcd, chk\hrft9l, chk\zzkkmi
*******************************************************************************************
```

Code,

```
file = File.open("C:/rake_check/input.txt", "r")

file.each_line.map do |line|
  next if line.chomp! =~ /^$|#/
  uno, deus, id = line.split(/\*+/) # also tried line.split("*")
  puts second
end
```

Comment: share the sample data to be split

Comment: the code you've shown (`line.split(/\*+/)`) splits the input code into 4 sections, the last of which contains only `\n`. Is this not what you're looking for? Question is unclear.

Comment: What do you mean by "split equally"? one and half records in each variable? o.O

Comment: @Md. Farhan Memon : input.txt file's content is the data to be split. Contents before every series of *s should be assigned as an array element. Eg myarray[2] should have the values before the last *s

`Record: C:/my_files/456_Milo_123-values.txt

#RakeBoss-Jan 21st Prod
[groups]
met = chk\rel_io_chk, chk\dev_op_io
div = chk\ret5cf, chk\plo09i, chk\cz0o9t, chk\lopikm
rakeonly = chk\ztylcd, chk\hrft9l, chk\zzkkmi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myarray = File.read('input.txt').split(/^\*{91}\n/)
```

(or, for example, `/^\*{5,}\n/` "split on a line of five or more asterisks" if you don't have exactly 91 each time.)

`/\*+/` means "one or more asterisks", which has several dangers: you might get an asterisk somewhere inside the record and split on it, and you're not slurping up the newline so each record except the first will start off with one.

Comment: Thanks much , that helped